# I need power shell script to get pricing tier and App type of all the App services (Web apps and Function Apps) in Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-app-service-plans

Example:
Get all the details of App service with Pricing Tier and App type

Below given is power shell script to export Web app details but i am unable to fetch Pricing tier and App type of App service.

```
#Provide the subscription Id where the Webapps ,function apps resides
$subscriptionId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$currentTime=$(get-date).ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");    
$outputFilePath=".\AzureWebAppsReport-"+$currentTime+".csv"  

Set-AzureRmContext $subscriptionId
$result=@()   

# Get all the webapps  
$webapps =Get-AzureRMWebApp 
$AzSubscription = Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
$rmresources =  Get-AzureRmResource | ?{ $_.Sku -NE $null}

# Loop through the webapps  
foreach($webapp in $webapps)  
{  
 $info = "" | Select Name,State,LOCATION,ResourceGroup,SUBSCRIPTION,AppServicePlan,PricingTier

foreach($rmResource in $rmresources) { 
        if($webapp.ResourceGroup -eq $rmResource.ResourceGroupName) {
            $info.PricingTier = $rmResource.Sku
            } 
        } 

        $info.Name = $webapp.Name 
        $info.State = $webapp.State 
        $info.LOCATION = $webapp.LOCATION
        $info.ResourceGroup = $webapp.ResourceGroup
        $info.SUBSCRIPTION = $AzSubscription.Name
        $info.AppServicePlan=$webapp.ServerFarmId

    #Add the object with above properties to the Array  
    $result+=$info 
}
$result | ft Name,State,LOCATION,ResourceGroup,SUBSCRIPTION,AppServicePlan,PricingTier

#Export the result Array to CSV file  
$result | Export-CSV $outputFilePath -NoTypeInformation
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and include what you have tried so far (any PowerShell code you have written) and any issues you're running into.

Comment: From the screenshot, looks you got the Pricing tier and App type, what is the issue?

Comment: @JoyWang that is for reference, I need these two highlighted columns which i am unable to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try my sample below, it works fine on my side.

```
$AzSubscription = Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId "<subscription-id>"
$result=@()  
$webapps = Get-AzWebApp
foreach($webapp in $webapps){
    $Tier = (Get-AzResource -ResourceId $webapp.ServerFarmId).Sku.Tier
    $obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $webapp.Name
        State = $webapp.State
        Location = $webapp.Location
        PricingTier = $Tier
        AppType = $webapp.Kind
        ResourceGroup = $webapp.ResourceGroup
        Subscription = $AzSubscription.Name
    }
    $result += $obj
}
$result | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\webapps.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

The `.csv` file will be like below:

[image]

Comment: Getting app type blank

Comment: @RahulTripathi07 Well, maybe there are differences in `Get-AzureRmWebApp` between the old `AzureRm` and the new `Az` module, actually I test it with `Az`, I notice you are using `AzureRm`, so I convert my script to that and give you. I recommend you to use the new `Az` module, becasue the `AzureRm` has been deprecated and will never be updated, just uninstall it and install `Az` module, follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/migrate-from-azurerm-to-az?view=azps-2.8.0), then use my updated script.

Comment: @RahulTripathi07 Hi, could you tell me why not accept the answer? It solved your issue.